# Simple message passing between 'background.js' to 'contentScript.js'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to apply the following flow :

binding for keys in the `background.js` , when pressing them :
Sending message from `background.js -> contentScript.js`
Sending response from `contentScript.js -> background.js`

Here is the `menifit.json` definitions:

```
  "background" : {

    "scripts" : ["background.js"],
    "persistent" : true
    },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],      
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
    ],
```

The binding part is working fine.

Here is the code in `background.js` :

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
        });
    });
```

Here is the code in `contentScript.js` :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(HandleMessage);

function HandleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
    {
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});        
    }
};
```

This is the error that i'm getting:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://fejkdlpdejnjkmaeadiclinbijnjoeei/background.js:64:26
    at disconnectListener (extensions::messaging:338:9)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:397:22)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:93:26)
    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:379:35)
    at EventImpl.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:403:17)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatch] (extensions::utils:93:26)
```

In case of changing

```
console.log(response.farewell);
```

to

```
console.log("OK");
```

it is working fine , but that way i cant get the values from the `contentScript.js`

What should i change ?

Comment: Question should be edited to state that it is about a Chrome Extension, not a Chrome App. I have removed the google-chrome-app tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to send messages from the background page to the content script. From the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), you're using this code snippet to send messages from the background page:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
 console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

However, the docs clearly mention that the code mentioned above is to send a message **from** a content script. This is the reason why you probably get the error:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
Stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined
```

What you want to achieve is sending a request from the extension (background page) to a content script which requires you to specify the tab in which the content script is present:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
     console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});
```

I hope this clarifies things and gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: same thing, getting the same error.
Can you specified what do you mean by  "which requires you to specify the tab in which the content script is present:"  ?
the contentScript.js is only on my pc , is not part of any web page..

Comment: The content script runs on a webpage which is open a tab. This just specifies which tab do you want to send the message to.

Comment: Ok this is working now.
The problem was that the webpage was already opened, had to close it and reopen it again..

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to Send Message in Chrome Extension, you can refer to [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Usually use one-time request, for example:

In background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {  
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }); 
});
```

In contentscripts.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request.message);
  if (request.message == "hello") {
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  }
});
```

Comment: while doing that i'm getting 'undefined' for the console log in the response part..

Comment: @USer22999299 You have to sendResponse in contentscript use the listener function's third parameter, you can try with the above demo

Comment: While correct, this answer does not explain what was wrong. As such, not really useful. Compare with the accepted answer.