# Chrome extension console.log causes error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chromium: Version 49.0.2623.87 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

I started getting this error today, but my extension seemed to be working fine before today.  Perhaps Chromium got updated?

Anyway, whenever I call `console.log()` in a contentscript, it always causes an `anonymous function` error, and the script stops running.

It would be a great pain to remove all the debugging information in my script.  What could be the problem here?

Comment: `anonymous function` error occurs when you are trying to send messages from the background page to the content script. You can check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296181/simple-message-passing-between-background-js-to-contentscript-js). It will also be helpful if you will post your contentscript.js and background.js.

Comment: It seems that whenever console.log() is called, it is registered as an error, but the more serious errors are marked by a red icon.

Comment: The `anonymous function` merely says under which context the console.log() is called.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually NOT an error.  The Chrome extension settings page **always** logs an error whenever `console.log()` is called.

These "errors" are normal whereas more serious errors will be indicated by an icon with a red mark.